# Laravel 8: 404 CSS file not found, even after file is loaded?

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel, .htaccess

I'm getting this following 404 error even though I've the CSS files in right directory, I've coded them correctly in my webpage header and they're getting loaded as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Files Loading Correctly]

[image: Header Code]

[image: File Directory]

[image: 404 Errors]

Still somehow I'm getting this following error, it's trying to find the CSS files in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/assets/css`
whereas I've redirected them to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/assets/css`.

I tried to work on .htaccess, as I think that's where from the problem is occurring, I've enabled `RewriteEngine` in .htaccess, still no luck.

Here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you check if this problem with css only or with any assets within asset function ?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHatem Yeah, rest of the files are working fine! For a test, now I created that directory in public as admin/assets/css/(here I pasted all the files), now it's working. But I need a real fix on this.

Comment: Asset function depends on the location of where index.php is located, so if index is inside public your code is should work but approximately your index is out public folder so you need to add public/ to your path

Comment: To the `asset('')` path?

Comment: Yes, in the beginning of your path

Comment: Those header files are getting loaded correctly, as you can see in the first screenshot, but when I refresh my page, in Chrome debug the error is occurring from somewhere else, like it's redirecting to 'admin/assets/css' which doesn't even exist.